# The best estimation of the function $\vartheta(x;q,a)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider the function $$\vartheta(x;q,a)=\sum_{p \leq x ,q|(p-a)}\log p=\frac{x}{\phi(q)}+O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^C}).$$
If the Riemann Hypothesis is ture, in the case $q=a=1$ we have $$|\psi(x)-x|<\frac{\sqrt{x}(\log x)^2}{8\pi}.$$
Now in the general case how well can the estimation be?  (Can assume some further hypothesis like the GRH in the comment)

Comment: You will need GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions, not just RH.

Comment: Hi ZZP, and welcome to the MathOverflow. This comment is just to say that there's a typo in the first text line below the first formula (**true**, not **ture**) and if you what to scale properly the round brackets in the big-$O$ term in said formula, you could use the TeX commands \left and \right placing them respectively before the opening bracket and the closing bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want. On the one hand Montgomery conjectures that the estimate

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \vartheta(x; q, a) - x \right \rvert = O_\epsilon \left(q^{-1/2} x^{1/2 + \epsilon} \right),$$

holds under GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions for $q \ll_\epsilon x^{1 - \epsilon}$, and this error term is best possible for $q$ close to $x$ in size. On the other hand Iwaniec and Kowalski's book contains the following estimate from the same hypothesis:

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \vartheta(x; q, a) - \frac{x}{\phi(q)} \right \rvert = O \left(x^{1/2} (\log qx) \right).$$

I am sure if one is careful one can track down an explicit implied constant, but I am not aware of this being done. Since most likely one cannot get away from dependence either on $q$ or some $\epsilon$, this may not be an interesting problem.

Comment: Thank you, it's helpful.

Comment: The first display does not seem right. For $x=1$ the LHS is $1$, while the RHS is $O(q^{-1/2})$, a contradiction.

Comment: @GHfromMO Perhaps I missed an assumption... looking at the statement it seems one should have to assume $q = O_\epsilon (x^{1- \epsilon})$. Indeed, one would not expect uniformity beyond that, since even Elliott-Halberstam only asserts moduli up to that range.